# Django: redirecting a view and using include()

Tags: python, django

I'm essentially trying to make my URLs more readable by incorporating a slug that is *not* used for lookup purposes in my views. Previously, I had this in my main URLconf:

**urls.py**

```py
path('<int:team_pk>/', TeamDetails.as_view(), name='team_details'),
path('<int:team_pk>/', include('tracker.urls', namespace='tracker')),
```

So I had urls like `mysite/1/stuff` and `mysite/1/more/stuff`.

Then I added a slug field to my Team model. The behavior I want is for any url that only includes a `team_pk` to be redirected to an expanded URL that incorporates the slug. For example, `mysite/1/` should redirect to `mysite/1/team_1_slug` and `mysite/1/stuff` should redirect to `mysite/1/team_1_slug/stuff`. It's this latter behavior that I'm having trouble with.

I modified my URLconf to this:

```py
path('<int:team_pk>/', TeamRedirectView.as_view(), name='team_details'),
path('<int:team_pk>/<slug:team_slug>/', TeamDetails.as_view(), name='team_details_redirected'),
path('<int:team_pk>/<slug:team_slug>/', include('tracker.urls', namespace='tracker')),
```

Then I have a simple view to redirect:

```py
# views.py
class TeamRedirectView(generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        team = get_object_or_404(models.Team, pk=self.kwargs['team_pk'])
        return reverse('team_details_redirected', kwargs={'team_pk': team.pk, 'team_slug': team.slug})
```

This works for redirecting `mysite/1/` to `mysite/1/team_1_slug`, but any url tag that points to a url inside the `tracker` app throws a reverse error because I'm not supplying `team_slug` to the url tag.

So I'm basically trying to get my RedirectView to be a little more universal and add this slug to any url without having to manually supply it to every url tag. Is that doable?

Comment: You should include the namespace, so `reverse('tracker:...', ...)`, so with the `tracker:` prefix.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying correctly, I need to set up a separate RedirectView for every url in the tracker app? So `reverse('tracker:url1', ...)` and `reverse('tracker:url2', ...)`, etc.? Is there no way to do it in a more DRY fashion?

Comment: no, or at least not at the moment.